# Can you begin a sentence with an emotion?

Tags: adjectives, british-english, translation, syntactic-analysis, passive-voice

Is it incorrect to begin a sentence with an emotion?

For example:

> "Afraid and alone, he no longer wished to continue on."

I'm translating some work from a foreign language into English, but I would like to keep the original sentence structure if possible. Starting the sentence with "being" or "as he was", just doesn't seem to give the same feel.

Comment: That is grammatical. It is fine as is. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sentences don't begin with emotions, they begin with words, in this case, the adjectives *afraid* and *alone* modifying *he*. They are perfectly acceptable as written, and that they reflect emotions is completely irrelevant to their grammaticality.

> Furious and humiliated, he no longer wished to continue on.
>
> Footsore and soaked, he no longer wished to continue on.
>
> Having already won $10,000, he no longer wished to continue on.

Comment: Would it act as an adverb?

Comment: @varfirstName Would what act as an adverb?

Comment: The entire phrase "Furious and humiliated"; does it act as an adverb like "Today" or "Yesterday"?

Answer (score 0):

It is correct to start off a sentence with emotions till you are using the right set of punctuation.

1. You can consider emotions to be kind of interjections (http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/interjections/what-is-an-interjection.html)
2. Take another example of starting a sentence with the (http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/starting-a-sentence-with-however-right-or-wrong)
3. Another way to look at it is that since the emotion comes earlier, it prepares the reader with the right set of emotions to read ahead.
4. On a lighter note: It reminds me of Star Wars or should I say, "Star wars, it does remind me of".